# data.table: Mark before/after occurrence of symbol within groups

Tags: r, data.table

Feel free to edit this title to make it more understandable/generalizable...

I have a **data.table** object with 3 columns that form groups (`id`, `id2` `pol_loc`).  Within these groups are row observations and there will be an asterisk at some row for each group or an `NA`.  I'd like to efficiently make an indicator column for each group of the row relative to the asterisks (before - 1, after - 0).  Here is what the data table looks like:

```
    id id2 pol_loc non_pol cluster_tag
 1:  1   1       3      do          NA
 2:  1   1       3     you          NA
 3:  1   1       3       *          NA
 4:  1   1       3      it          NA
 -------------------------------------
 5:  1   2       3     but           4
 6:  1   2       3       i          NA
 7:  1   2       3       *          NA
 8:  1   2       3  really           2
 9:  1   2       3     bad          NA
 -------------------------------------
10:  1   2       5     but           4
11:  1   2       5       i          NA
12:  1   2       5    hate          NA
13:  1   2       5  really           2
14:  1   2       5       *          NA
15:  1   2       5    dogs          NA
 -------------------------------------
16:  2   1       4       i          NA
17:  2   1       4      am          NA
18:  2   1       4     the          NA
19:  2   1       4       *          NA
20:  2   1       4  friend          NA
 -------------------------------------
21:  3   1       4      do          NA
22:  3   1       4     you          NA
23:  3   1       4  really           2
24:  3   1       4       *          NA
 -------------------------------------
25:  3   2      NA      NA          NA
    id id2 pol_loc non_pol cluster_tag
```

**Desired output**:

Here is the desired output:

```
    id id2 pol_loc non_pol cluster_tag   before
 1:  1   1       3      do          NA        1
 2:  1   1       3     you          NA        1
 3:  1   1       3       *          NA       NA
 4:  1   1       3      it          NA        0
 ----------------------------------------------
 5:  1   2       3     but           4        1
 6:  1   2       3       i          NA        1
 7:  1   2       3       *          NA       NA
 8:  1   2       3  really           2        0
 9:  1   2       3     bad          NA        0
 ----------------------------------------------
10:  1   2       5     but           4        1
11:  1   2       5       i          NA        1
12:  1   2       5    hate          NA        1
13:  1   2       5  really           2        1
14:  1   2       5       *          NA       NA
15:  1   2       5    dogs          NA        0
 ----------------------------------------------
16:  2   1       4       i          NA        1
17:  2   1       4      am          NA        1
18:  2   1       4     the          NA        1
19:  2   1       4       *          NA       NA
20:  2   1       4  friend          NA        0
 ----------------------------------------------
21:  3   1       4      do          NA        1
22:  3   1       4     you          NA        1
23:  3   1       4  really           2        1
24:  3   1       4       *          NA       NA
 ----------------------------------------------
25:  3   2      NA      NA          NA       NA
    id id2 pol_loc non_pol cluster_tag   before
```

**MWE**

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    id2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), pol_loc = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA), non_pol = c("do", "you", 
    "*", "it", "but", "i", "*", "really", "bad", "but", "i", 
    "hate", "really", "*", "dogs", "i", "am", "the", "*", "friend", 
    "do", "you", "really", "*", NA), cluster_tag = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "4", NA, NA, "2", NA, "4", NA, NA, "2", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "id2", "pol_loc", 
"non_pol", "cluster_tag"))

library(data.table)

setDT(dat)
```

**EDIT** If it makes it easier or more efficient the `NA`s can become `0` or `1`  It makes no difference and I'm guessing that's more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
dat[, before:=1-cumsum(non_pol=="*"), by=.(id, id2, pol_loc)][non_pol=="*", before:=NA,]
```

Comment: This one is much better.

Comment: Nice simple but I wouldn't have thought to go this route.  Awesome.

Comment: `1-cumsum` looks bizarre to me for creating a 0/1 vars. I'd go with `before := +(.I <= .I[which(non_pol=="*")])` or `1:.N <= which(non_pol=="*")`

Comment: @Frank is that more efficient?

Comment: I find `cumsum(x=="*")` very natural but  `+(seq_along(x)>=which(x=="*"))` very bizarre.

Comment: @TylerRinker No, I don't think so, just preference, as Khashaa suggested :)